# Android WebView File upload option is not working

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a created very simple WebView app, but the problem I face is uploading button from the website is not working.

This means if I want to select files or images from the gallery nothing happens.

I have tried all the answers from this site, nothing really works for me.

Below is the code. Please Help me fix this issue.

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding binding;

    WebView mWebView;

    public String url ="https://google.com/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        Log.d(TAG1, "Main Activity Open");

        mWebView = binding.myWebView;

        ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setTitle("Loading");
        progress.setMessage("Wait while loading...");
        progress.setCancelable(false); // disable dismiss by tapping outside of the dialog
        progress.show();

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);


        if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html"); //Change path if it is not correct
        } else {
            mWebView.loadUrl(url);
        }

        //  wb.loadUrl(url);
        progress.dismiss();

    }
```

Comment: I see no upload button.

Comment: upload button is on the website. which is in the WebView

Comment: On the website? On google.com?  But istill see no button.

Comment: google is just for example bro, but the main thing is that file is not uploaded. I can't show the actual website.

Comment: Use your own minimal html page wich contains such a button. Then you can show the source with the button.

Comment: You should add some webview setting to set upload enabled.

Comment: but what setting?

Comment: Android Studio will show all possible settings as soon as you typed .set...

Comment: do this solve your problem ? https://github.com/sspencer10/webview , is has an exemple to how to make your webview able to upload files